# Geometric Meaning of Luna's Slice Theorem

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-topology, soft-question

**I found the Luna's Slice Theorem very Technical. It will be helpful if someone illustrates the  geometry involved in the theorem. Also why this theorem so useful?**

This is Luna's Slice theorem from a lecture note of Jean-Mac Drezet [Luna's Slice Theorem and applications- Lecture note by Jean Mac Drezet](http://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~jean-marc.drezet/papers/Wykno.pdf) 
[image: Luna_Slice]
And this is the Version of Luna's theorem when the point x is smooth- 
[image]

Also I will use the opportunity to attract attention to one of another question where I asked the meaning of a topological slice of a point- [Slice of a point of a topological space](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1025810/slice-at-a-point-of-a-topological-space)

**Is there any other resource to know more about Luna's Slice Theorem?**

Comment: This maybe better suited to mathoverflow. Not because some people here can't probably interpret the theorem above and give intuition, but rather you want someone who has experience using it. You are more likely to find such a person there.

Comment: @AlexYoucis: Yes Alex, I just realized it and have posted in Mathoverflow few hours back- "http://mathoverflow.net/questions/188006/etale-slice-theorem"